# Case statement with date and string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following error, ORA-01841
`(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999 and not be 0`

The error is coming from the below case statement.

Any help on what's going on and how to fix?

SQL

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN NVL(uap.us_pend_dt, act_d_dt) >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF."','YYYY-MM-DD'),'mm/dd/yyyy')
THEN NVL(uap.us_pend_dt, act_d_dt)
ELSE CASE WHEN NVL(act_d_dt, SYSDATE) <TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('".HIRE_DATE_CUTOFF."','YYYY-MM-DD'),'mm/dd/yyyy')
THEN act_d_dt
ELSE ua_dt
 END
  END AS h_DT
```

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values as strings?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but isn't this a paste from a block of code, which actually builds this SQL query? The `PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF` and `HIRE_DATE_CUTOFF` look a bit like values to be passed from the application, to the query. If so, you either are doing this wrong (and have the code "bleed" to the query) or have wrong values of those "variables". Either way, consider using bind variables / parameterized queries / prepared statements, and save yourself and the world another SQL injection attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert a string `".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF."` to a date. I just did the following and got an identical error:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF."', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual;
```

Is `.PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF.` (with periods) the name of a column in your table? If so then omit the single quote characters, e.g.:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF.", 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual;
```

Of course this will give an altogether different error [`ORA-00904: ".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF.": invalid identifier`] if you run as is! So I think you might want something like the following (I'm assuming the other date columns are actual dates, and the cutoff columns are `VARCHAR2` columns that are storing dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(uap.us_pend_dt, act_d_dt) >= TO_DATE(".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF.", 'YYYY-MM-DD') THEN COALESCE(uap.us_pend_dt, act_d_dt)
         ELSE WHEN COALESCE(act_d_dt, SYSDATE) < (TO_DATE(".HIRE_DATE_CUTOFF.", 'YYYY-MM-DD') THEN act_d_dt
         ELSE act_d_dt
       END AS h_dT
  FROM mytable;
```

Note that I also got rid of the extraneous `CASE` statement and converted the Oracle-specific `NVL()` function to the ANSI-standard `COALESCE()` function.

**EDIT:** In the event that your `*_dt` columns are strings and not dates, best to convert them to dates using `TO_DATE()` *before* comparing - that way you're comparing dates to dates.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, your date columns are stored as dates.  So, do the comparison as *dates* not *strings*:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NVL(uap.us_pend_dt, act_d_dt) >= TO_DATE('".PENDING_DATE_CUTOFF."', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             THEN NVL(uap.us_pend_dt, act_d_dt)
             WHEN NVL(act_d_dt, SYSDATE) < TO_DATE('".HIRE_DATE_CUTOFF."', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             THEN act_d_dt
             ELSE ua_dt
        END) AS h_DT
```

You also don't need the extra `case` expressions.

Comment: An anonymous downvote on what looks like a correct answer?

Comment: I downvoted as the answer doesn't even attempt to address the error the OP received, which is being caused by the call to `TO_DATE()`